# A sql statement to return results if the record is not updated 24 hours after they are created

Tags: sql, date, time, dateadd

I am thinking how to write a SQL statement to return records for the ticket is not updated 24 hours after it is created. Thank you!

What I want to do is to fire up an email once the ticket is not updated 24 hours after it is created. Something like this but the result is not correct.

```
Select * 
from tickets 
where (ticket_createddate > dateadd(hour,24,current.timestamp))
```

Comment: in what platform do you store your database?

Comment: Did you intend to ask a question? Or were you just providing a status report on your current efforts? (The syntax for the SELECT statement will depend, in part, on the DBMS you are using (Oracle, SQL Server, MySQL), the names and datatypes of the columns available in the `tickets` table, and the criteria by which you determine whether and when a given ticket "has been updated". Without that, we'd just be **guessing**, and **not** giving an answer (to a question you didn't ask.)

Answer (score 0):

From this:

```
Select * 
from tickets 
where (ticket_createddate > dateadd(hour,24,current.timestamp))
```

I see a couple of things.  First, shouldn't

```
current.timestamp
```

be

```
current_timestamp?
```

Next, shouldn't

```
dateadd(hour,24
```

be

```
dateadd(hour,-24
```

Finally, shouldn't there be something about when the field was last updated?

Comment: +1. It certainly seems that we would need a way to determine that a ticket "has been updated", and if so, **when** the ticket was updated.

Comment: Also it should have been `<` instead!